# Erro : too few arguments to function 'Fdelta'

Tags: c

Quando tento declarar uma função ocorre o erro too few arguments to function 'Fdelta' oque poderia ser?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia copiar o código?
Assim nós poderiamos testa-lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observando o seu *código*, percebi que você declarou a função `Fdelta()` recevendo 3 parametros `inteiros`, e quando você vai utilizar você não está passando os parametros, esse erro é referente a falta de parametros na função `Fdelta()`, para você resolver, coloque: `Fdelta(A, B, C);`, assim você estará passando os valores de `A`, `B` e `C` como parametro para a função.